# Program execution time

Tags: java, c++, c, memory, execution

Is there a software/website where I can submit my C, C++ and Java codes and get statistics like the program execution time, memory used ? I'm interested in doing a comparision of the same code in different languages and getting an estimate of which data structures/operations are better suited for which language.

Comment: If you looking for a software it is advisable to provide what platform you are. Ie: win/linux/mac/...

Comment: Why don't you test it on our local system first, wouldn't that be sufficient for comparison purposes?

Comment: @Avada- I have all three, so tell me for any one or all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paste your program at [ideone](http://ideone.com/) and it will tell you the execution time and memory consumption.

Comment: Actually this is EXACTLY what I was lookin for! Thanks a bunch. I'll be back to up vote when I have a reputation of 15.

Answer (score 7):

Do it yourself. On a *nix machine (e.g. Linux and OSX) just run from the terminal:

```
time java YourJavaProgram
```

or

```
time ./YourCProgram
```

On Windows, you can [write a little batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/228056/windows-equivalent-to-unix-time-command) to do the equivalent.

Comment: This may get biased by different startup times prior to the actual execution of some code.

Comment: He asked for program execution time. The start up time is part of the program execution time.

Comment: That's right, I just wanted to add this not because I'm not sure if the OP is aware of that distinction (specific part versus complete program performance).

Answer (score 1):

That's called **[benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_%28computing%29)** and you can do it yourself. The thing is that many other variables affect the results, so it would be best to control the environment and measure the performance of your program trying to eliminate as much external variables as possible.

For example, it is advisable to do all the measurements of all the programs on the **same** machine, with the **same** environment, as much as that can be achievable.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all. If you tell him he can do it himself, shouldn't you say how that might be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get benchmark of functions, using "time" is not fair. You should write following in your language.

```
time_before = get_now()
// do something
span = get_time() - time_before
```

Answer (score 1):

The total used / free memory of an program can be obtained in the program via java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();

The runtime has several method which relates to the memory. The following coding example demonstrate its usage.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PerformanceTest {
  private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

  public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
    return bytes / MEGABYTE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I assume you will know how to create a object Person yourself...
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
      list.add(new Person("Jim", "Knopf"));
    }
    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Run the garbage collector
    runtime.gc();
    // Calculate the used memory
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
    System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: "
        + bytesToMegabytes(memory));
  }
}
```

Use System.currentTimeMillis() to get the start time and the end time and calculate the difference.

```
package performance.test;

class TimeTest1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
      total += i;
    }

    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(elapsedTime);
  }
}
```